# JPA CriteriaQuery with LEAST and GREATEST functions

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am have a problem where i need to join two tables using the LEAST and GREATEST functions, but using JPA CriteriaQuery.  Here is the SQL that i am trying to duplicate...

```
select * from TABLE_A a
inner join TABLE_X x on
(
  a.COL_1 = least(x.COL_Y, x.COL_Z)
  and
  a.COL_2 = greatest(x.COL_Y, x.COL_Z)
);
```

I have looked at [CriteriaBuilder.least(..)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#least(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression)) and [greatest(..)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#greatest(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression)), but am having a difficult time trying to understand how to create the `Expression<T>` to pass to either function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that CriteriaBuilder does support calling LEAST and GREATEST as non-aggregate functions, and can be accessed by using the CriteriaBuilder.function(..), as shown here:

```
Predicate greatestPred = cb.equal(pathA.get(TableA_.col2),
                    cb.function("greatest", String.class,
                            pathX.get(TableX_.colY), pathX.get(TableX_.colZ)));
```

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way to compare two columns and get the least/greatest value is to use the CASE statement.

In JPQL, the query would look like

```
select a from EntityA a join a.entityXList x
  where a.numValueA=CASE WHEN x.numValueY <= x.numValueZ THEN x.numValueY ELSE x.numValueZ END
  and   a.numValueB=CASE WHEN x.numValueY >= x.numValueZ THEN x.numValueY ELSE x.numValueZ END
```

You can code the equivalent using [CriteriaBuilder.selectCase()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#selectCase()) but I've never been a big fan of CriteriaBuilder. If requirements forces you to use CriteriaBuilder then please let me know and I can try to code the equivalent.

CriteriaBuilder least/greatest is meant to get the min/max value of all the entries in one column. Let's say you want to get the Entity that had the alphabetically greatest String name. The code would look like

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery query = cb.createQuery(EntityX.class);
Root<EntityX> root = query.from(EntityX.class);

Subquery<String> maxSubQuery = query.subquery(String.class);
Root<EntityX> fromEntityX = maxSubQuery.from(EntityX.class);
maxSubQuery.select(cb.greatest(fromEntityX.get(EntityX_.nameX)));
query.where(cb.equal(root.get(EntityX_.nameX), maxSubQuery));
```

I created a sample Spring Data JPA app that demonstrates these JPA examples at

https://github.com/juttayaya/stackoverflow/tree/master/JpaQueryTest

Comment: Unfortunately, defining the least/greatest predicates via CriteriaBuilder is a requirement in my case.  Because, as you point out,  both greatest & least are aggregate functions which operate on a single expression (e.g. Column), we would need to convert the two columns into a single column, possibly through a pivot or subselect operation as you have suggested above.  Fortunately, there is another way to call the function that I wish to implement...