# JPA - Syntax error parsing SELECT GREATEST(c.field, mc.field), LEAST(c.field, mc.field) FROM table

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I need to get the greatest and least value between two fields. I'm using JPA 2.1 with EclipsLink.

Here's my query simplified:

```
SELECT GREATEST(c.min, mc.max), LEAST(c.max, mc.max) 
FROM
   MethodCategory mc, OperationMethod om, Client c 
       JOIN
   User u ON c.id = u.client.id
WHERE
   om.method = 1
   AND om.method.category = "SUPER"
   AND om.isDeleted = false 
   AND om.user = u
   AND u.id <> 1 
   AND c.isOnline = TRUE 
   AND c.isActive = TRUE;
```

It does work fine on MySQL Workbench, as a raw sql query but when I replicate this query to my `entityManager.createQuery(query)` I get an exception.

Here's how I replicate the query to JPA:

```
TypedQuery<Object[]> query = em.createQuery("SELECT GREATEST(c.min, mc.min), LEAST(c.max, mc.max) "
                + " FROM\n"
                + "    MethodCategory mc, OperationMethod om, Client c \n"
                + "        JOIN\n"
                + "    User u ON c.id = u.client.id \n"
                + " WHERE\n"
                + "    om.method = :method \n"
                + "    AND om.method.category = :categoryName \n"
                + "    AND om.isDeleted = false \n"
                + "    AND om.user = u \n"
                + "    AND u.id <> :userId \n" 
                + "    AND c.isOnline = TRUE \n"
                + "    AND c.isActive = TRUE \n",
                Object[].class);
```

Whenever I execute this JPQL query I get this exception:

```
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT GREATEST(c.min, mc.min), LEAST(c.max, mc.max)  FROM (...)
[14, 15] The SELECT clause has 'GREATEST' and '(c.min, mc.min)' that are not separated by a comma.
[72, 73] The SELECT clause has 'LEAST' and '(c.max, mc.max)' that are not separated by a comma.
```

It really makes no sense to me this exception. I'm clearly separating the GREATEST() and LEAST() with a comma and GREATEST , (value) does not make any sense.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: My suggestion would be to look at this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35759093/jpa-criteriaquery-with-least-and-greatest-functions) on the same topic that details the use of CriteriaBuilder to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: @JustinKyleParton thanks. That will be my worst case scenario solution. I'm trying to avoid to rewrite this query into CriteriaBuilder at the moment.

Comment: i havent used this, so i wont put it as an answer, but go to this page [EclipseLink Special Operators](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#EclipseLink_special_operators) and try using that to achieve what you are wanting.  Also look at the Operators just below it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following solution, a mix of `MIN/MAX` with `CASE THEN`

Here's the query:

```
SELECT  
MIN(CASE WHEN (c.min < mc.min) THEN mc.min ELSE c.min END) as min, 
MAX(CASE WHEN (c.max < mc.max) THEN c.max ELSE mc.max END) as max  
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The aggregate functions `greatest` and `least` are not supported by JPA 2.0. They are not mentioned in the [syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html). Have you tried `min` and `max` instead: `max(c.min,mc.min), min(c.max,mc.max)`?

Answer (score 1):

The other option could be to augment the JPA database dialect for MySQL. I'm not familiar with EclipseLink but with Hibernate it would be something like this:

```
import org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;

public class CustomMySQL5InnoDBDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect {
    public CustomMySQL5InnoDBDialect() {
        super();

        registerFunction("greatest", new StandardSQLFunction("greatest", null));
        registerFunction("least", new StandardSQLFunction("least", null));
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't try this as I solved my problem and I've no time to refactor/try this approach but this seems like an interesting solution. +1